# setting g++ mode to C++11

Tags: c++11, cmake, g++

I am trying to build cmake source, which requires C++11.
The build halts and apparently the complaint is that C++11 is not detected. The g++ mode is actually set to -std=gnu++17

This is part of the console log

```
---------------------------------------------
CMake 3.18.20200919, Copyright 2000-2020 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
Found GNU toolchain
C compiler on this system is: gcc   
C++ compiler on this system is: g++  -std=gnu++17  
Makefile processor on this system is: make
g++ has setenv
g++ has unsetenv
g++ does not have environ in stdlib.h
g++ has stl wstring
g++ has <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>
---------------------------------------------
g++  -std=gnu++17      -DCMAKE_BOOTSTRAP    -DCMake_HAVE_CXX_MAKE_UNIQUE=1  -c $HOME/Apps/CMake-master/Source/cmAddCustomCommandCommand.cxx -o cmAddCustomCommandCommand.o
```

This is part of the error in the log file...

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/unordered_map:35:0,
                 from cmake_bootstrap_11920_test.cxx:4:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support \
  ^
cmake_bootstrap_11920_test.cxx:7:2: error: #error "Compiler is not in a mode aware of C++11."
 #error "Compiler is not in a mode aware of C++11."
  ^
cmake_bootstrap_11920_test.cxx:70:16: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
   int Member = 1;
```

Looking around on the web, I noticed that C++11 is only available after gcc version 4.6.
I checked my version, and it seems to be above.

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609
```

I understand the -std=c++11 flag is used to enable the C++11 features in g++, but I don't seem to know what I am doing in this case.
I tried editing the CompileFlags.cmake file, but no change occurs.

I came upon [this page](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/4a275f63206be052f9ab32a35a58681469374ba9) which points to the cmake source I am using.
It says...

```
bootstrap: Require compiler mode aware of C++11

Some compilers have enough features enabled in their default modes to
pass our simple C++11 unique_ptr check but do not enable enough to build
CMake.  Poison this case so that we choose one of the explicit `-std=`
options for such compilers.
```

Not sure what that means exactly.

How exactly do I change the g++ mode, to C++11, so that on running the bootstrap command, C++11 is used?
Or, in other words, how do I change std to point to C++11 (-std=c++11)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your description of the problem is quite ... vague for being able to help you. Please, consult [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly (at least, include the **exact** error message you got).

Comment: If you are Ubuntu its easier to install CMake using apt and then build it from source.  Bootstrapping is only necessary if you don't have CMake in the first place.  Also if bootstrap doesn't work then reporting a bug report to kitware is probably a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was not even thinking about using cmake, just following the instructions on the page. I think I will try using cmake. @dboy can you please give your post, a bit of detail, since the set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) is already set for use, but only if a few  conditions are not met. I don't know if I should remove those conditions.

Comment: @fdk cmake was a breeze. That's what I like to see. A build with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have g++ version 5.4.0 in your host PC installed, which is good, cause it means this is also supports the C++11, which you want to use.
To set it up, you could define it in your *CMakeList.txt* file:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

that should do the trick.
Please also check the documentation:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html

Usually, I would suggest to use the latest standard that you compiler is supporting (https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html), cause you'll get also the latest features introduced in that standard. Exception for this rather in case you are working with legacy codes.